# TNAS how to install wget

Tags: software-installation, wget, nas

I have a TNAS F5-221.
How to install wget? I'm getting: wget command not found.
I tried: `yum install wget`, `apt install wget`. I’m logged through ssh as root. Is there work around for it?

Comment: is curl installed, so you can use this instead?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Terramaster TNAS but I do have quite a number of QNAPs. On these the usual approach is to install Entware from https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki.

Entware takes over `/opt` and uses its `opkg` package manager, so

```
export PATH="/opt/bin:$PATH"
opkg update
opkg install wget
```

Thereafter,

```
wget ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If no apt and no yum, you have to get it from somewhere else. Luckily this an intel based system (file /sbin/init or uname -a) you can download a already compiled wget binary from somewhere else and copy it onto the system. You got to take into account libraries already installed. Maybe curl is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am late to the party... but someone may find this question...

My Terrmaster F4-210 has busybox as part of the OS... (*and* busybox *is* already compiled with `wget`)

So connect via `ssh sudo su` (become `root` using the admin password - or like me, set up a key!) *then* simply:

```
ln -s busybox /bin/wget
```

*That* should do it...